# Another SDK like OpenNI

Tags: kinect, openni

I am taking information for my project and I need to see libraries ans SDKs. Searching in the web I found that OpenNI has a lot of functions and when I try to found another SDK, I dont find any other. I am working with a Kinect and a XTION so I need an SDK who works in both.

Is there any other SDK o set of libraries that works well in both?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the Point Clound Library (PCL). They claim to have support for both. I've used it with Kinect, it works quite well.

------> [Point Cloud Library](http://pointclouds.org/)